# the element type 'List<widget>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am trying to add data using for loop in gridview but it is showing some error. Here is my code for component

```
return new GridView.count(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
    mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
    children: <Widget>[getList()],
);
```

getList() code

```
List<Widget> getList() {
  List<Widget> childs = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    childs.add(new ListItem('abcd ' + $i));
  }
  return childs;
}
```

But it is showing compile time error.

```
The element type 'List<widget>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'
```

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Here you are wrapping a list as list

```
children: <Widget>[getList()],
```

This should rather be

```
children: getList(),
```

Answer (score 25):

Just use spread operator:

```dart
return new GridView.count(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
    mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
    children: <Widget>[...getList()],
);
```

Comment: Thanks..It worked. But could you please explain what happens with a spread separator?

Answer (score 15):

Using the spread operator is one way of solving this issue. But there is also another one that involves the use of `toList()` method.

`children` property requires list of Widgets. However, in your case, it becomes the following:

```
return new GridView.count(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
    mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
    children: [
      [
        ListItem('abcd 0'),
        ListItem('abcd 1'),
        ...
      ]
    ],
);
```

Therefore,

**Solution 1**

the wrapping should be `children: getList(),`

**Solution 2 (spread operator)**

`children: <Widget>[...getList()],`

As a side note, you might encounter this issue when trying to use something like a `map()` method. In that case, the usage of `toList()` method comes in handy. For example,

`children: someListOfObjects.map((el) => Text(el)).toList(),`

Answer (score 12):

There are two methods I found working.

**Method 1 - Simple**

This method is supported in  the latest version of `flutter`

```
var list = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]; 

child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
          for(var item in list ) Text(item)
      ],
),
```

**Method 2 - A bit Complex**

Tested in `Flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.7` and `Dart 2.7.0`, we can iterate over the list of objects as follows:

Iterate over the list of objects

```
...data.map((f) => paragraph(f.title, f.description)).toList(),
```

Custom widget

```
Column paragraph(String title, String description) {
  return new Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        child: Text(title),
      ),
      Container(
        child: Text(description),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

Data: List of objects

```
List<AboutUsData> data = [
    new AboutUsData(
      title: 'Our Vision',
      description:
          'OUR VISION',
    ),
    new AboutUsData(
      title: 'Our Mission',
      description:
          'OUR MISSION',
    ),
    new AboutUsData(
      title: 'Our Values',
      description:
          'As we grow as a company',
    ),
  ];
```

Comment: How can I get the index from that .map?

Comment: for now you can manually count the number of iterations by some variable, let say `count`. set `count = 0`, and then add `count+=1` based on each iteration.

Answer (score 9):

Since the answer was not satisfactory for me, so I found another solution.

Flutter gives you the possibility to write conditions on a single line also in the graphic, so you can insert a cycle on a single line and then insert the other different widgets. This is a practical example in response to the main question:

```
 Column(
    children: <Widget>
      [
        for (int i = 0;
        i < workouts.series.length;
        i++)
          "//CREATE N YOUR WIDGETS//",
          new Text(
          "${workouts.series.length} x ${exerciseWorkout.repsToDo} ",
          style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black87,
          fontSize: 16,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          )
      ],
     )
```

Comment: I test it. Only first widget will be iterated by loop. Other will be just added after

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, i have a list of:

```
List<Info> li = [
    Info(name: "oussama", height: 180, date: DateTime.now()),
    Info(name: "mehdy", height: 150, date: DateTime.utc(1997, 05, 14)),
    Info(name: "ahmed", height: 190, date: DateTime.utc(1997, 04, 11)),
    Info(name: "sofiene", height: 160, date: DateTime.utc(1995, 07, 13)),
    Info(name: "mohamed", height: 150, date: DateTime.utc(1994, 01, 17))
];
```

and i want it to display them in a column which return a `list<Widget>` so i followed the same as sad @Günter Zöchbauer: i created a function `getList()`:

```
List<Widget> getList() {
    List<Widget> childs = li
        .map((e) => Row(children: <Widget>[
              Text(e.name, style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25)),
              Text("${e.height}", style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25)),
              Text("${e.date}", style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25))
            ]))
        .toList();
    return childs;
  }
```

then i assigned it to `Column`:

```
body: Container(
 child: Column(
   children: getList()
))
```

it worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

To fix this error

```
The element type 'T' can't be assigned to the list type 'Object'.dartlist_element_type_not_assignable
```

You can use this in the Equatable package
@override
List<Object?> get props => [value];

Answer (score 0):

is to initialize it as an empty list:

```
List<Widget> widgetList = List<Widget>.empty(growable: true);
```

with the suggested constructor

```
list<widget> widgetlist = <widget>[];
```